# adding and removing class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, class

Searched around the place yet I still couldn't find a solution that I matched my situation. So I decided to ask it myself. Here's what I want to do:

- If one of the `<li>` is clicked, that particular `<li>` will be given a new class named "bla" and any other `<li>` will lose "bla" class.
- If a `<li>` which already has "bla" class is clicked, it will lose the "bla" class.
- if ANYTHING else on the page outside the `<ul>` is clicked, "bla" class will be removed from all the `<li>`.

---

The HTML:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Item One</li>
      <li>Item Two</li>
      <li>Item Three</li>
      <li>Item Four</li>
    </ul>
```

---

Thank you...

Comment: A combination of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) / [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and a bit of logical thinking might get you on the right path. Try it yourself, and post some updates. It's not that hard.

Comment: Hahaha... I have looked into the matter for almost 2 hours, yet only managed to find the answer for the first 2 wishes. I have no lead for the last one, which is why I decided to ask the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('ul > li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('bla').siblings().removeClass('bla');
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('ul').length > 0) return;
    $('ul > li').removeClass('bla');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bySBP/)

Answer (score 0):

You can code up something in these lines

```
// Bind a click event on document
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // Use e.target to get the element that is currently selected
    var $this = $(e.target);
    // It item is li or not having a class add it 
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'LI' && !$this.hasClass('active')) {
         $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SsEk4/1/)**